# Recreate the PvP Rampager's amulet

Tags: guild-wars-2

In PvP, the amulet are used to summarised all the armour, weapon and Trinkets stats.

How did they come with the [Rampager's Amulet](http://www.gw2db.com/items/26058-rampagers-amulet)

```
+284 Power
+798 Precision
+569 Condition Damage
+284 Vitality
```

Plus there is an upgrade in it adding:

```
+125 Precision
+75 Condition Damage
+45 Power
+45 Vitality
```

How can I get these stats with PvE armours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to recreate the Rampager's amulet outside of sPvP.

PvP has different stat combinations available than in PvE. The Rampager's amulet seems to duplicate a set that is half Precision / Condition Damage / Power (Aka, the Rampager prefix), and half Precision / Condition Damage / Vitality , [a combination that is not present on PVE gear.](http://www.gw2db.com/items/armor/coats?filter-item-rarity=6&filter-item-minimum-required-level=80&filter-item-maximum-required-level=80&filter-item-minimum-Precision=1&filter-item-maximum-Precision=9999&filter-item-minimum-Vitality=1&filter-item-maximum-Vitality=9999) (if the link doesn't work, click "Show Filters" and try the link again) The Jewel (equivalent to PvE accessory upgrade slots) replicates these ratios.

Almost all level 80 gear in Guildwars 2 has a 3-stat combination, but not all possible combinations (including variations in the Primary stat, which there's always twice as much of) are in the game. The Halloween Event added in a new combination (Magic % / Power / Condition Damage ) of stats, so it seems likely that future updates may also fill in the missing distributions.

Comment: I tried calculation of my own, trying to reach these number. Almost started a "Are PvP stats the same as PvE". It seems it is not. Cleary. Thx